# Only show if date is less than 14 days ago

Tags: mysql

I have three tables - notices, notices_read and companies. Notices contains a list of notices for clients which are displayed in a web app and notices_read is an indicator that they have clicked and read the message so it is not shown again whilst companies holds the company info including their join date. Additionally, I only want the notice to be shown to clients who joined more than 14 days ago.

Everything works bar the 14 day ago part - if I remove that line the notice shows correctly depending on whether there is a value in notices_read but if I add the date line in then, whilst there is no error, nothing is returned.

```
companies
+-----------------+
| id | datestamp  |
+-----------------+
| 1  | 2012-12-20 |
| 2  | 2012-12-20 |
| 3  | 2012-11-20 |
| 4  | 2012-11-20 |
+-----------------+

notices_read
+-----------------------------+
| id | company_id | notice_id |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 3          | 1         |
+-----------------------------+

notices
+----------------------+
| id | title  | active |
+----------------------+
| 1  | title1 | 1      |
| 2  | title2 | 0      |
+----------------------+
```

- Notice 2 should never show as it is not set to active
- Notice 1 should not show to company 1 or 2 as they are not 14 days old
- Notice 1 should not show to company 3 as it has already been read
- Notice 1 should show to company 4 as it has not been read and company 4 is older than 14 days

Here is my query:

```
Select
  notices.description,
  notices.id,
  notices.title,
  notices_read.company_id,
  companies.datestamp
From
  notices Left Join
  notices_read On notices.id = notices_read.dismiss_id Left Join
  companies On notices_read.company_id = companies.id
Where
  notices.active = 1 And
  companies.datestamp <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 14 Day) And
  (notices_read.company_id Is Null Or notices_read.company_id != '$company_id')
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the joins and not the date though I realise my date was wrong too - I have changed the from and joins around as I need to show data from notices and not from notices_read and it is still not working but I think it is because I am joining table 1 to table 2 and then trying to join table 2 to table 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you only need to use `DATE_SUB`

```
DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 14 Day)
```

The full query would be:

```
Select
  notices.description,
  notices.id,
  notices.title,
  notices_read.company_id,
  companies.datestamp
From
  notices_read Left Join
  notices On notices_read.dismiss_id = notices.id Left Join
  companies On notices_read.company_id = companies.id
Where
  notices.active = 1 And
  companies.datestamp <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 14 Day) And
  (notices_read.company_id Is Null Or notices_read.company_id != '$company_id')
```

Comment: Note that, because of the `WHERE`-clause's requirement that `companies.datestamp` be non-null, your second `Left Join` is actually equivalent to an `Inner Join` (in that any records without `companies` components will be discarded). Furthermore, this also means that your `notices_read.company_id Is Null Or` has no effect, since that join will never succeed when `noticed_read.company_id` is null.

Comment: I got this to work by doing three selects but your answer on the date (which was my original question) was right so I have accepted your answer - thank you